# How to deal with rouding in BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have this code to get a percentage:

```
final BigDecimal price = BigDecimal.valueOf(215).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
final BigDecimal daysOfThisReservation = BigDecimal.valueOf(3).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);

final BigDecimal dayPrice = price.divide(daysOfThisReservation, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);

System.out.println(dayPrice); //71.67
System.out.println(dayPrice.multiply(daysOfThisReservation).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)); //215.01
```

I have a reservation that costs $215.00, this reservation has 3 per day,
so, the price is $71.67.

If I try to get the original value again, I have some problems with rounding, 71.67 * 3 = 215.01

How to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: Don't try to reverse it? What kind of answer are you expecting? There's no magical way to reverse rounding...

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you looking for an exact number of dollars and cents that you can multiply by 3 to give $215?  I suspect you won't find one.

Comment: Not in base-10 fractions at least. Wouldn't be a problem with base-3 fractions.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Are you proposing a new currency system, with 81 cents in the dollar?  (Many countries used to have a system with 240 pence in a pound)

Comment: This is a snippet of the code, I have many reservations, and I want to calc the percertage of total value that each reservation represents. I don't if it's a good practive rouding manualy or just acept this diference

Comment: 'I had some problems' is not a problem description. Try harder.

Comment: If you're calculating a percentage, why do you think you need to round anything, other than perhaps the final percentage itself?

Comment: @Erwin: "Not in base-10 fractions at least. Wouldn't be a problem with base-3 fractions". Actually, would not be a problem with fractional types at all, i..e types that (internally) contain a numerator and a denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My feeling is that the problem here is not one of throwing away the original price, but rather of throwing way valuable information by truncating fractional values to two decimal places.  If you kept even one more decimal place, you wouldn't have this problem.

Here's an example that keeps 6 places of precision to allow enough precision for doing hundreds of operations on values for which I eventually want only two significant decimal places.  You will never have rounding problems with 6 decimal places if you only care in the end about 2 places.

This code keeps 6 places except when printing the single-day price, at which point it rounds to 2 places.

```
final BigDecimal price = BigDecimal.valueOf(215).setScale(6, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
final BigDecimal daysOfThisReservation = BigDecimal.valueOf(3).setScale(6, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);

final BigDecimal dayPrice = price.divide(daysOfThisReservation, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN).setScale(6, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);

System.out.println(dayPrice.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN));
System.out.println(dayPrice.multiply(daysOfThisReservation).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)); //215.01
```

Result:

```
71.67
215.00
```

Comment: This is the answer!! I change my code to round to 2 decimal only in presentation and thats works fine. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at it this way. Memory and communication is cheap.

```java
BigDecimal totalPrice = new BigDecimal(double 215.00);
int numNight = 3;
BigDecimal perNightPrice = totalPrice
    .divide(new BigDecimal(int numNight), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
    .setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```

At this point, you have three variables. Given both memory (primary RAM and secondary disk/DB) and communication is cheap, you can just retain totalPrice variable. You don't need to reverse-engineer it out from perNightPrice and numNight.

I have been in this kind of situations before. We just change the API and/or data table definition to allow us to retain one more piece of data (unless you are scrapping for memroy in Lunar-Lander -- which I doubt it's the case since Lunar-Lander does not calculate hotel prices).

Answer (score 1):

Can be improved to a certain accuracy?

```java
final BigDecimal price = BigDecimal.valueOf(215).setScale(10, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
final BigDecimal daysOfThisReservation = BigDecimal.valueOf(3).setScale(10, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```